# AntTweakBar causes graphics driver to crash

Tags: c++, user-interface, directx

I know that this is an AntTweakBar specific question, but I am only asking it here because there isn't a dedicated AntTweakBar forum on their website.  I was wondering if anyone experienced a similar issue to see if there was a quick fix before I started diffing files from examples for hours.  I am writing a game in DirectX 11 on Windows 7 using the Microsoft Compiler v9.0 in Visual Studio 2008.

```
I have followed all of the instructions in integrating AntTweakBar into my 
DirectX 11 application, however a problem occurs when my swap chain presents the
back buffer, the entire application will crash and subsequently my graphics 
driver will crash (a dialog pops up in the system tray saying that the video 
driver crashed).
```

Checklist of things I have done:

- I have followed all of the instructions [here](http://www.antisphere.com/Wiki/tools%3aanttweakbar%3adownload).
- I am calling all of the proper initialization functions on startup, calling the proper TwDraw() function on each frame, and calling the TwTerminate() function on exit.
- I have set up my include and library paths to correctly point to the AntTweakBar framework.
- I have placed the AntTweakBar.dll in the same directory as my executable.
- I have added AntTweakBar.lib in my linker settings for Visual Studio 2008.

Yet I am still experiencing a graphics driver crash after all of this... :-/

I could post a video on YouTube detailing the crash and I could also post my solution if necessary, it's quite crucial to get AntTweakBar operating in my framework.  I am also willing to get on Skype if someone is willing to help there me as well (skype: b.triana).

Thank you for your time!

Comment: actually, there is a forum, but it's not easy to find: https://sourceforge.net/p/anttweakbar/discussion/

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, AntTweakBar is early age graphics product that works better with OPENGL, well, yes it works with DX as well, I would think it works with early versions of DX as well like DX9... , I am not sure people are still updating anttweakbar to support new generation of APIs, if they are not, then you have problems. I am assuming you did follow those steps.

The second thing is people don't need anttweakbar in DX world , DirectX have provided DXUT bundled with itself provide similar neat UI hinters, I would suggest you take a look at that.

Comment: I appreciate the tip on DXUI, will give it a look.

Comment: Actually, after Googling for half an hour, I cannot find a single resource on "DXUI".  I also checked the Windows DirectX documentation in the SDK itself and no dice.

Comment: @btcode sorry, I must have forget the name, it's DXUT related, I would suggest you to check the newest sample codes for SDKs, like nvidia's framework for DX, phyx library sample.